# clear text onclick - textfield

Tags: javascript, html

What is the best method to clear text in a text field, when the user clicks on it?

I.e., if the text search field says "search" and when they click it, it clears the value.

Comment: What language? What platform?

Comment: Are you talking about an HTML text field? WinForms? Cocoa? Give us some context, please.

Comment: asp.net? android? what are u using???

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could do like:

```
<input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'search') {this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value ='search'}">
```

Answer (score 17):

`<input name="foo" placeholder="Search" />`
The placeholder tag is a new HTML5 tag that does exactly what you want to do here.

Answer (score 6):

Normal HTML:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function clearThis(target){
        target.value= "";
    }
    </script>
    <input type="text" value="Search" onfocus="clearThis(this)" />
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clearThis(target){
        $(target).val = "";
    }
</script>
<input type="text" value="Search" onfocus="clearThis(this)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can simple set the value of the contorol to an empty string in the OnFocus event handler.

Answer (score 0):

If jquery's an option, I'd consider the [watermark plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/)

It achieves what you're after, but with a bit more style